# bind html page content(without tag) to textarea using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using textarea to bind the html page. using http.get() I got html page and stored into one scope variable. Now I want to remove all html tags only content page I need.I want to load only html page into textarea

Thanks in advance

My html page

```
    <html>

<body>
    <p>
    </p>
    <div> Hi,
      &nbsp;</div>
    <div>
        <br />
    </div>
    <div>
            Test Email has been received successfully.
    </div>
    <div><br /></div>
    <div>Warm Regards,</div>
    <div><br /></div>
    <div>System Administrator</div><br />
    <p>
        {{ProjectName}}
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-bind-html="scopeVariable"></div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml.

> To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available, for example, by including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core AngularJS). In order to use ngSanitize in your module's dependencies, you need to include "angular-sanitize.js" in your application

**For text box :**

You would have to manually convert it into plain text by removing the tags.
Here's how - 
http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/13297/

Comment: Make sure you include $sanitize module if you do this, otherwise I don't think it will load. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Comment: ng-bind-html is removing only html and body tag from the html file

Comment: in my html page I have used lot of <p> and <div>tag. ng-bind-html just removing <html> and <body> tag and showing but I want to remove entire tag of the html page

Comment: yeah, ngsanitize I have included in my controller page

Comment: @Searcher Can u share the sample html you are using?

Comment: u directly giving that html into scope variable. I am getting that html file using http.get(). But Not due to that. Because I also tried to give directly eventhough it is displaying same with tag except html and body tag

Comment: I am binding that model to textarea so that it is not displaying correctly If I remove that text area and bind for div it is working But I need to bind for textarea only

Comment: fine. But alignment is not looking good. how do I align it again

Comment: and ur replacing <tag> brackets. Here I am sending one link to user. that link will not work right? I want to send link with this email

Comment: @Searcher You shouldn't be using text area for this purpose. There's always going to be limitations while presenting an html as string in textarea

Comment: Because I am going to send Email to user. That Email Content should be visible for editing. due to that i am using textarea. How should I achieve this

Comment: Is there any other way to load the html content with link reference